# Algorithm for detecting a finite limit of time-series numbers

Tags: algorithms, mathematical-analysis, time-series-analysis

Is there a well known and proven algorithm to find the TOP (finite) limit of a set of points, which are time based metrics? I'm looking for an existing implementation, in order not to invent the wheel of something which already exists.

This is what I have in mind, but it is a bit hard to configure the right parameters, and requires iterations:

Run over the numeric values of a series

1. Calculate L which is the top limit, and E (E is configurable), where 2*E is the convergent stripe around L.

   - Most points, P percentage, except of anomalies/noise, are below the top line of L+E (P is configurable, ranging somewhere at 95-99% range).
   - A Linear line around the last X points (Linear Regression) has a minor slope of +/-S (X and S are configurable)
2. The algo uses a stored state of a previous maximum limit - max-L.

   - In case L which was calculated in (a) is lower than max-L, it is considered a local max which is discarded
   - If L is greater than max-L then it is considered a new max limit and stored as the new max-L

The question is do you know of an existing algorithm to fulfil this, or add any suggestions to the algorithm I created. Thanks!

[image: Inspiring graph - although there's no input function, just a set of points]

**NOTE**: 
Just to be clear, as an input I have a set of data points, each with a real value and a timestamp. There is no function input, just those points. This mean, that the algorithm might detect a limit, which when inspecting all the historical data points would look like a true maximum limit, but then later in time new data points would be higher and yield a new higher limit. meaning that the algorithm I'm looking for would only find "local" limits.

Comment: What is your input? Are you given a function, or do you only get a set of data-points? If the latter, I think you need to assume that the strip containing all values with $x>K$ for some $K$ is strictly decreasing in $K$, as otherwise the series can seemingly converge and then e.g. become strictly increasing at some time later.

Comment: thanks @Discretelizard the input is a set of data points, each with a real value and a timestamp. If I understand you comment correctly, I believe that at a single point in time it can get concluded that a limit was reached - taking into account all past data points, giving a local max limit. but then later on in the future it  can happen that a new higher limit would reach. I don't see how this can get avoided, and therefore this is a limitation I can live with. again, finding a limit and then in the future understanding that it was not the real limit

Comment: Yes, you can only hope to find 'local' limits if you are given finite information about an infinite series. Please [edit](https://cs.stackexchange.com/posts/106596/edit) these points you address in the comment into your question to make it clearer. Thank you!

Comment: thanks again for the clarification @Discretelizard. I just updated the question

Comment: Have you looked at change point detection?

Comment: Thanks @D.W. I haven't looked at it yet

Comment: ...I haven't looked at it yet, it looks promising for segmenting the series and checking the top ones trends. I'll see if I can use it. Thanks!